# Why cannot I see all featured questions even if the questions don't have tags I ignore?

Tags: support, bountied-tab

Here's [C++ Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b?sort=featured&pageSize=50),

My ignored tags: `facebook`,`visual-studio`,`visual-studio-2010`,`directx`
I see the page like this:

[image: featured-screenshot1]

And [here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKBsA.png), how I see the page when I log out.
If you zoom in the image you'll see that no question has the tags I have ignored...
So why cannot I see them ?

Comment: Because the number at the top is most likely incorrect.

Comment: What is the *count* on the page (number of questions tagged, just to the right of your screenshot)? I cannot reproduce your problem; for me *one* of the questions is ignored, and if I explicitly hide ignored tags I still see '7' at the top right.

Comment: What happens if you go to your preferences page in your profile and uncheck the 'hide ignored tags' checkbox at the bottom?

Comment: @3ventic: Why would it be? I see 7 bountied questions there. Even if I hide ignored tags (for me that drops the number of results to 6).

Comment: Not sure that I follow, but I see one on that list tagged visual-studio. And the others probably aren't really that common considering it's a search on the c++ tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'ignored tags' list in the right-hand side is *elided*. It only shows the first *four* tags.

Click on the little `...` next to those four tags to see them all. You are ignoring more tags than you think.

You can also edit the full list in your [preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) and either remove ignored tags, or uncheck the '*hide ignored tags* checkbox.

Comment: thanks, it's solved now :)